# Running my Junit Tests in Terminal

Tags: java, junit

I just started to work with JUnit. I ran my test through Intelij IDEA and it is all fine but when I'm trying to run my test in terminal using this code:

```
java -cp /junit4.10/junit-4.10.jar:. /Users/maidini/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/test/CalculatePriceTest.java
```

I am getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /Users/maidini/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/test/CalculatePriceTest/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Users.maidini.IdeaProjects.HelloWorld.test.CalculatePriceTest.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Do you have any idea what should I do to be able to successfully run my test in terminal as well? I am using Mac Lion as well.

Answer (score 4):

You first have to compile your code using `javac`; loading `.java` source files on your classpath won't work. Remember to add both your unit test class, and the actual class that you're testing. And any dependencies they might have. Maybe you'll want to bundle them in a `.jar` file, too, so your command-line won't get too long. Also, don't forget to recompile every time you change your code or your test.

This can get hairy pretty quickly. Instead, I recommend you use a build tool, like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). With a proper Maven build, you can just type `mvn test`, and Maven will handle the dependencies, compilation, and running the tests for you.

If you don't want to use Maven, you could also look into [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) (preferably in combination with [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)), or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/), or any other Java build tool.

Comment: I already compile the class and it's fine but still getting the same error

Comment: agree on using Maven (or any other build tools).  @MaryamAyd, are you sure that you know what you are trying to do with your command?  You are running your class as an java application, but not running any unit test

Comment: @MaryamAyd You also should refer to the class you want to execute, not the file it's defined in. So if your class lives in the package `com.maryamayd`, you should put `com.maryamayd.CalculatePriceTest` on the commandline instead of `/Users/maidini/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/test/CalculatePriceTest.java`. Although even that probably won't work, since it doesn't have a `main` method. Please use a proper build tool.

Comment: I'm completely a beginner in java as I am a .Net person and in .net everything is very straight forward.What do you mean by com.maryamayd pachakge? Should I add my stuff into a package?

Comment: @MaryamAyd Heh, I'm just migrating from Java to .NET. For me, Java is the straightforward one :). Java packages are like C#'s namespaces, so yes, adding things to packages is a Good Thing™. Maven is like MSBuild (I guess) except that it will also download and manage dependencies for you. You don't have to do that manually.

Comment: Do you have some clear steps which I can follow to do everything to be able to run my tests?

Comment: @MaryamAyd [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) and [Maven Getting Started Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) are, I think, good places to start.